# How to find the most common words from a folder of text files in java

Tags: java, count, directory, cpu-word

So i have a code that reads a txt file from a given directory and it counts the words in it perfectly. But for the life of me i cant find out how to do the same thing but for a folder of txt files.

Here is the code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        Scanner txtFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\testfolder\\test.txt"));
        while (txtFile.hasNext()) {
            String word = txtFile.next();
            if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                int count = map.get(word) + 1;
                map.put(word, count);
            } else {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
        txtFile.close();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

here is a part of the output

```
been=2
upvotes=1
don't=1
leading=1
about=1
your=1
I've=1
Follow=13
Elder=1
1%=3
would=1
```

Comment: Read the `File` API. Given a directory you can get a list of all the files in the directory. Then you iterate through the List and and process each file one at a time.

Comment: i think i am on the right track now. Thank you !